# What does "lean forward" means in that context

Tags: marketing

Firm that I work in started a new marketing campaign. There are some posters with slogans and one of them has words: "Forget your comfort zone lean forward build an amazing career". What those words mean according to you (especially "lean forward")?

For me it suggests that the woman from photo builds her career basing on some sexual relations with employers, but I believe it was not the message.

[image: New poster]

Comment: I'd guess they mean _become more engaged_ (essentially the opposite of _sit back_) but it's not a particularly idiomatic choice of words.

Comment: Having seen the graphic I think that the text is meant to be taken as a list of phrases (a bit like a bullet list) rather than a single sentence. "Lean forward" still doesn't make a lot of sense to me, it must be an idiom of which I am not aware.

Answer (score 2):

In 2013, Sheryl Sandberg, the chief operating officer of Facebook published a book titled, "Lean In: Women, Work, and the Will to Lead".

There's also an associated website, LeanIn.org

The book is meant as career advice for women, especially those in traditionally male-dominated businesses.  The advice to *lean in* means something like: *adopt an attitude and a posture that suggests that you're fully engaged - as if you were in a meeting and you were leaning forward in your chair eagerly or aggressively participating.*

The phrase, "lean forward," on the poster seems to be referencing that newly popular phrase. The copy writer either got the phrase wrong, was trying to avoid a copyright dispute, or was thought they were being clever.

Comment: I agree that's what the phrase probably means. There are other (somewhat similar) senses in which I've seen it used (e.g. by MSNBC), "to adopt a progressive position" or "to look to the future rather than the past", and it's used with a meaning somewhere between the two as a slogan by MSNBC but they don't fit as well here. https://www.inc.com/eric-v-holtzclaw/how-i-learned-to-lean-forward-every-day.html https://www.mediaite.com/online/msnbcs-new-brand-lean-forward-the-biggest-campaign-in-network-history/

Answer (score 0):

No, it is definitely **Not** suggesting that the woman uses sex to advance her career :)    There is an expression *"to lean into"* that seems to becoming more common, which means to confront life's challenges and problems rather than trying to avoid them. This piece of marketing seems to be a variation on that "lean into" idea.